# How to check if bzr "Tree is up to date" ? (to only build when necessary)

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bzr

I'm setting up a script to download, build and install a big project (that uses bazaar) and want to trigger the build process only if the "bzr update" does NOT return "Tree is up to date at revision n" ; How can I do that ? Are there specific return codes to look for ? Ideally I would be able to do that on other VC systems, namely git & svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exit code of `bzr missing URL` to decide whether you need to do `bzr up` and rebuild. The exit code is 0 if there are no updates, 1 otherwise.

In `bzr missing URL` you only need to specify `URL` once, afterwards you can use the `:parent` shortcut, or you could set `parent_location` in `.bzr/branch/branch.conf` and use `:parent` always.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to just grep for `Tree is up to date` in the `bzr up` output I imagine. There is no return code you can use.

Alternatively, you can use `bzr missing :parent` before you run `bzr up` to see if there are any revisions that are missing locally.